# How to display subtotals using a smart table in sapui5

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I am using a smart table of type Analytical Table to display items. I have a requirement to display line item subtotals and i dont how to achieve it. I am using [explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.personalization.example5/preview) example as reference. I have checked this [blog](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3913823) but I cant seem to marry whats happening in the back end with front end part.

Is there anyone who has kind of an end to end solution? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Kind regards

Comment: Why don't you calculate the subtotals your self?